# CORS Support in Asterisk PBX Web Server

Tags: javascript, asterisk, amazon-ami, asteriskami

Aterisk PBX has a built-in web server, I am trying to login to My Asterisk PBX through AMI over HTTP from my Local Computer. My problem is that when I call the Login Action over HTTP the Manager is connected but response's MIME type is "text/plain", but I need the MIME type to be "text/javascript".
The Error below is raised in Chrome Developer tool:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: http://172.16.100.100:8088/asterisk/rawman?action=Login&username=username&secret=pass&_=1394447007551". HYPERLINK "http://localhost:16328/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"jquery-1.10.2.js:8516
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple server, it not designed to give you correct mime-type.

You have 3 options

1) load jquery from google CDN

2) Put javascript inside html page.

3) Extend server(it is opensource, your remember?) for your need.

Comment: What exactly wrong in my answer? Have you ever read asterisk.org source code?